# Is there a way to reuse tomcat database connection pool through datasource?

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling, tomcat8

I was successful in creating a connection pool to my spring boot application using tomcat connection pool from application.properties file with parameters, but the problem is that i don't know how to use the existing connection from the pool into my class where i have separate database interactions am stuck.

```
spring.datasource.type = org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource 
spring.datasource.url = ...
spring.datasource.username = ...
spring.datasource.password = ...
```

By using DataSource here returns null reference exception.

```
public class connectToDB{

@Autowired
private DataSource db;
```

I need to acquire a connection from the existing pool here. what will be the approach.

Comment: does this class `connectToDB` is spring bean? show some code this is not sufficient

Comment: As @Deadpool said add more details to the problem statement. Also can you try declaring a bean of type org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource and then setting the properties through poolProperties. We use this approach and it works.

Comment: i am trying to something like this in connecToDB Class..

Comment: public class connectToDB{
 @Autowired
 private DataSource db;
  
  Utility util = new Utility();
  
 
    // get Page
 public List<String> getPage() throws ClassNotFoundException, 
     SQLException, NamingException {
  List<String> Pages = new Vector<String>();
  Connection con = db.getConnection();
  Statement stmt=(Statement) con.createStatement();  
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select DISTINCT PageName from ....");
  
  while(rs.next()) {
   
   Pages.add(rs.getString("PageName"));
   
  }
  con.close();
 return Pages;
 }
}

Comment: If you want to post code (or any additional information, like copying/pasting error messages or stack traces), all you have to do is edit your original post.  Don't try to put code in a comment; don't post it as an "answer".